# GLOP: read .mps

Tags: or-tools

I have an LP in a .mps, and I'm testing it on top solvers. Usually, there's a command line supplied, which can can do:

```
read model.mps
optimize
```

GLOP doesn't have a command line, but it supports python. What's a minimal script to do that?

Maybe on the way suggest how to try other supported solvers such as PDLP and CLP?

---

Relatedly, maybe a hint about a specific feature that I'm looking for if it's supported:

Specify an initial solution, and use the solver for a limited time to find a better feasible solution

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4510587/find-a-feasible-but-not-optimal-solution-to-a-large-lp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a binary called solve in ortools/examples/cpp

```
solve --solver glop --input file.mps
```

Comment: Right, and you need to build it first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73381230/or-tools-build-examples-on-vs2022