# or-tools: build examples on vs2022

Tags: or-tools

I've downloaded the binaries: or-tools_VisualStudio2022-64bit_v9.3.10497

I'm using vs2022 on win10. My shell has cygwin in the path if it's related.

I ran

`%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`

cl.exe is in the path, and which.exe finds it.

I ran `make test_cc`, but it complained

> the cl command was not found in your PATH
> exit 127
> make: *** [Makefile:271: test_cc] Error 127

The var CXX_BIN was empty even though `which cl` returned the correct path. I set it manually to cl.
Then, there was a complaint about echo and a newline, which I commented out. Then, it couldn't find `md`, so I created manually `md objs`.
A few of the examples were built, but then it stopped with another error. For now, I just got what I want:

`make run SOURCE=examples/cpp/solve.cc`

but probably there was an easier way to get it?

---

I tried to build it from the source using cmake. Doesn't work off-the-shelf as well:

```
Build abseil-cpp: OFF
...
CMake Error at C:/prj-external-libs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:824 (_find_package):
  By not providing "Findabsl.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "absl", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "absl" with any of
  the following names:

    abslConfig.cmake
    absl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "absl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "absl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "absl"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/deps.cmake:33 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:304 (include)
```

---

If finds `gurobi95.dll`, but it can't find the function `GRBtunemodeladv`.

On failure, solve.exe crashes with (unknown) names in the stack trace. Need to add debug symbols and graceful error handling.

---

cmake looks more promising, and I was missing dependencies. Should give it a flag `-DBUILD_DEPS:BOOL=ON`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. OR-Tools depends on few external dependencies so CMake build will try to find them using the idiomatic `find_package()` => your distro/env(vcpkg ?) must provide them, just regular CMake stuff here.
   ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html
   note: we provide few `findFoo.cmake` here https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/main/cmake
2. We also provide a meta option to build statically all our dependencies, simply pass `-DBUILD_DEPS=ON` cmake option at configure time.
3. You can also build only some of them, please take a look at
   https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/main/cmake#dependencies
4. Concerning Gurobi and `GRBtunemodeladv` symbol, this one has been removed by last version of Gurobi so we fix it in v9.4/main/stable branch...
   see: https://github.com/google/or-tools/commit/d6e0feb8ae96368523deb99fe4318d32e80e8145